# Can I change my about.me address?

Tags: about-me

Is there a way to change my [about.me](https://about.me/) address?

Eg.: I registered as `about.me/123abc` but now I'd like to have `about.me/987xyz` address.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Update:

This is no longer possible.

> Your url isn’t editable, but you can register a new address – simply register at http://about.me with a different email address.

[Source](https://aboutme.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/221017767-I-don-t-like-the-URL-I-chose-How-do-I-change-it-Pro-).

---

<del>This is now possible.</del>

<del>To change it, go to *Account Settings* → *My Information* → *Change My Username* (small link under the *Save* button) → follow the instructions in the modal overlay.</del>

[image]

<del>[Source](https://support.about.me/forums/60495-feedback/suggestions/1196759-ability-to-change-about-me-username).</del>

<del>Please note that it will take a some time for the change to be approved, period while you will not be able to login (at least in my experience).</del>

---

> <del>**How to: Change my about.me url/email address**</del>
>
> <del>**Your url isn’t editable**, but you can register a new address – simply register at http://about.me with a different email address.</del>
>
> <del>Because your about.me email is tied to your url, create a new url to get a different about.me email address as well!</del>

[Source](http://support.about.me/knowledgebase/articles/29053-how-to-change-my-about-me-url-email-address).

Comment: I don't see it. Is it available only in Pro???

Comment: source link now https://aboutme.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/221017767-I-don-t-like-the-URL-I-chose-How-do-I-change-it-Pro-

Answer (score -4):

You can now change this under settings.

Comment: Could you add some instructions?